# Automate a way to change or toggle a keyboard shortcut with either Automator or Applescript

Tags: keyboard, mac, applescript, windows, shortcut

I'm remoting into my Windows box and would like to be able to change the shortcut for Mission Control on the fly.  Like a toggle switch.  Specifically the move left a space and move right a space.  I don't mind creating a Bash script to this either.  Whatever works.  Would it just be a matter of changing a plist somewhere? Note that I'm always using multiple desktops in both Windows and Mac.